# How to compile AndroidScreencast? (several errors)

Tags: java, android, linux, eclipse, ant

**Readme says**

```
Android Screencast
Homepage : http://code.google.com/p/androidscreencast/

***********************
HOW TO BUILD THE PROJET
***********************

Copy file "andrdoiscreencast.conf.example" to parent folder.
Rename it to "androidscreencast.conf".
Use your text editor to tune the configuration
Launch ant (with target dist or jnpl).
```

`

**androidscreencast.example.conf says this**

```
// The tag added to produced jar (androidscreencast-xxxx.jar)
version=DEV

// The location of your android sdk installation
android.sdk=/a/b/c/android-sdk-linux_x86-1.5_r3

// JAR signing for jnlp startup
sign.keystore=../my_keystore
sign.storepass=xxx
sign.keypass=yyy
sign.alias=zzz

// for auto deployement to google code "downloads" section
gc.username=aaa@gmail.com
gc.password=www
```

I have installed ADT bundle which includes Eclpise and SDK to ~/ADT/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030 so what should I write in location of sdk? should it be adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-**20131030/sdk** ?

Ive tried the above but it fails with

```
ant -v -f AndroidScreencast/build.xml
```

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.3 compiled on February 19 2014
Buildfile: /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.8 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/build.xml with URI = file:/home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/androidscreencast.conf
Build sequence for target(s) `jnlp' is [init, compile, dist, jnlp]
Complete build sequence is [init, compile, dist, jnlp, clean, gc, ]

init:
    [mkdir] Skipping /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/bin because it already exists.

compile:
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/build.xml:26: warning: 'includeantruntime' was not set, defaulting to build.sysclasspath=last; set to false for repeatable builds
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/MyInjectEventApp.jar skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/StreamUtils.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/StreamUtils.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/file/FileInfo.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/file/FileInfo.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ConstEvtKey.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ConstEvtKey.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ConstEvtMotion.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ConstEvtMotion.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/Injector.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/Injector.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/KeyCodeConverter.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/KeyCodeConverter.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/NullSyncProgressMonitor.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/NullSyncProgressMonitor.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/OutputStreamShellOutputReceiver.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/OutputStreamShellOutputReceiver.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ddmlib.jar skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/DataAtomOutputStream.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/DataAtomOutputStream.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/FilterImageOutputStream.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/FilterImageOutputStream.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/QuickTimeOutputStream.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/QuickTimeOutputStream.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/app/Application.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/app/Application.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/app/SwingApplication.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/app/SwingApplication.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogError.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogError.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogUrl.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogUrl.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JFrameMain.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JFrameMain.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JPanelScreen.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JPanelScreen.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JSplashScreen.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JSplashScreen.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/MultiLineLabelUI.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/MultiLineLabelUI.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/JFrameExplorer.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/JFrameExplorer.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/LazyLoadingTreeNode.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/LazyLoadingTreeNode.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/LazyMutableTreeNode.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/LazyMutableTreeNode.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/icon.png skipped - don't know how to handle it
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/pm/JFrameApps.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/pm/JFrameApps.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/worker/AccumulativeRunnable.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/worker/AccumulativeRunnable.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/worker/SwingWorker.java added as net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/worker/SwingWorker.class doesn't exist.
    [javac] Compiling 29 source files to /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/bin
    [javac] Using modern compiler
dropping /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/ddmlib-DEV.jar from path as it doesn't exist
    [javac] Compilation arguments:
    [javac] '-nowarn'
    [javac] '-d'
    [javac] '/home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/bin'
    [javac] '-classpath'
    [javac] '/home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/bin:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/usr/share/java/xmlParserAPIs.jar:/usr/share/java/xercesImpl.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/lib/tools.jar'
    [javac] '-sourcepath'
    [javac] '/home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src'
    [javac] '-g:none'
    [javac] 
    [javac] The ' characters around the executable and arguments are
    [javac] not part of the command.
    [javac] Files to be compiled:
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/StreamUtils.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/file/FileInfo.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ConstEvtKey.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ConstEvtMotion.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/Injector.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/KeyCodeConverter.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/NullSyncProgressMonitor.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/OutputStreamShellOutputReceiver.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/DataAtomOutputStream.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/FilterImageOutputStream.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/recording/QuickTimeOutputStream.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/app/Application.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/app/SwingApplication.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogError.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogUrl.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JFrameMain.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JPanelScreen.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JSplashScreen.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/MultiLineLabelUI.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/JFrameExplorer.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/LazyLoadingTreeNode.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/LazyMutableTreeNode.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/pm/JFrameApps.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/worker/AccumulativeRunnable.java
    [javac]     /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/worker/SwingWorker.java
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:11: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.AndroidDebugBridge;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:12: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java:12: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java:13: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.RawImage;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JFrameMain.java:34: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/Injector.java:12: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:18: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     IDevice device;
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:75: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private void waitDeviceList(AndroidDebugBridge bridge) {
    [javac]                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class AndroidDebugBridge
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JFrameMain.java:70: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private IDevice device;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JFrameMain
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JFrameMain.java:91: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public JFrameMain(IDevice device) throws IOException {
    [javac]                       ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JFrameMain
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     private IDevice device;
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class ScreenCaptureThread
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public ScreenCaptureThread(IDevice device) {
    [javac]                                ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class ScreenCaptureThread
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java:123: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public void display(RawImage rawImage) {
    [javac]                         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class RawImage
    [javac]   location: class ScreenCaptureThread
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/Injector.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     IDevice device;
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class Injector
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/Injector.java:35: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public Injector(IDevice d) throws IOException {
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class Injector
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java:13: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java:14: error: package com.android.ddmlib.SyncService does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.ISyncProgressMonitor;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java:15: error: package com.android.ddmlib.SyncService does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.SyncResult;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java:19: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     IDevice device;
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class AndroidDevice
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java:21: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public AndroidDevice(IDevice device) {
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class AndroidDevice
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/NullSyncProgressMonitor.java:3: error: package com.android.ddmlib.SyncService does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.SyncService.ISyncProgressMonitor;
    [javac]                                      ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/NullSyncProgressMonitor.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class NullSyncProgressMonitor implements ISyncProgressMonitor {
    [javac]                                                 ^
    [javac]   symbol: class ISyncProgressMonitor
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/OutputStreamShellOutputReceiver.java:6: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IShellOutputReceiver;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/OutputStreamShellOutputReceiver.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] public class OutputStreamShellOutputReceiver implements IShellOutputReceiver {
    [javac]                                                         ^
    [javac]   symbol: class IShellOutputReceiver
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.java:21: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.java:38: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     IDevice[] devices;
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JDialogDeviceList
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.java:40: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public JDialogDeviceList(IDevice[] devices) {
    [javac]                              ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JDialogDeviceList
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.java:95: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public IDevice getDevice() {
    [javac]            ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JDialogDeviceList
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/JFrameExplorer.java:28: error: package com.android.ddmlib does not exist
    [javac] import com.android.ddmlib.IDevice;
    [javac]                          ^
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/JFrameExplorer.java:34: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     IDevice device;
    [javac]     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JFrameExplorer
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/explorer/JFrameExplorer.java:77: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]     public JFrameExplorer(IDevice device) {
    [javac]                           ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JFrameExplorer
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         AndroidDebugBridge bridge = AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class AndroidDebugBridge
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:36: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         AndroidDebugBridge bridge = AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge();
    [javac]                                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable AndroidDebugBridge
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         IDevice devices[] = bridge.getDevices();
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/Main.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                 AndroidDebugBridge.terminate();
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   variable AndroidDebugBridge
    [javac]   location: class Main
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/injector/ScreenCaptureThread.java:100: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         RawImage rawImage = null;
    [javac]         ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class RawImage
    [javac]   location: class ScreenCaptureThread
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]             SyncResult result = device.getSyncService().pushFile(localFrom.getAbsolutePath(),
    [javac]             ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class SyncResult
    [javac]   location: class AndroidDevice
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/api/AndroidDevice.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]                     ISyncProgressMonitor.class);
    [javac]                     ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class ISyncProgressMonitor
    [javac]   location: class AndroidDevice
    [javac] /home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/src/net/srcz/android/screencast/ui/JDialogDeviceList.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]         return (IDevice)jlDevices.getSelectedValue();
    [javac]                 ^
    [javac]   symbol:   class IDevice
    [javac]   location: class JDialogDeviceList
    [javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
    [javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
    [javac] 39 errors

BUILD FAILED
/home/euphoria/androidscreencast/AndroidScreencast/build.xml:26: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.compile(Javac.java:1174)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Javac.execute(Javac.java:930)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)`

Total time: 7 seconds

**what does Launch ant (with target dist or jnpl) mean?**

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run this project at all because of the following error : -

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: androidscreencast (The system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main.access$000(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks !

Comment: Ive read through all of these errors and Im hoping that if i know what Launch ant (with target dist or jnpl) means I will do it correcty without errors.So what does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the file "androidscreencast.conf"** (which is a copy of "...example"):

Yes, enter path to your android-sdk-basedirectory (maybe /home/yourusername/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20131030/sdk/ in your case), build.xml expects a directory "tools/lib/" to be there:

```
android.sdk=/path/to/your/android/sdk/installation
```

If you don't know what to enter for...

```
sign.keystore=../my_keystore
sign.storepass=xxx
sign.keypass=yyy
sign.alias=zzz
```

...or run into trouble when it comes to signing/security, make yourself familiar with the "keytool" command - it's pretty simple once you get it. Basically you need to "keytool -genkeypair", or at least that's what I needed to do. then, edit the above lines from the config file to your needs. (You will know what to do after using "keytool".)

**"Launch ant (with target dist or jnlp)" means:**
Enter either "ant dist" or "ant jnlp" or both at the same time "ant dist jnlp" to compile/build androidscreencast. "dist" will create a subdirectory ("dist/") with the jar-files, "jnlp" does the signing (see above) of the jar-files.

**To run androidscreencast:**
Enter "dist/" directory, then type...

```
javaws androidscreencast-DEV.jnlp
```

(compare config file's first line: version=DEV)

Most likely you will run into trouble now.

**First Bugfix: Remove the "codebase=...googlecode..." (line 3) from the androidscreencast-DEV.jnlp file.** This will make the jnlp-file/javaws use local jar's instead of downloading from a outdated, non-existent URL.

**Second Bugfix:** When I enter "javaws" it's in fact "icedtea". Make sure you have **IcedTea 1.6.2 or higher**. (Some bugfix regarding null-pointer on application-initialization. Or something.)

**Third Bugfix: You may have to copy "MyInjectEventApp.jar" and "icon.png" files from the src-tree to correct places.** I think you have to copy "MyInjectEventApp.jar" to "bin/" and "icon.png" to "bin/net/srcz/android/screencast". (All inside the "AndroidScreencast/"-directory, not absolute linux filesystem paths!) ("grep" the source code folder for these two filenames to see the paths in the source code. Paths are relative to bin/net/srcz/android/screencast, which is the location of the "Main.class". A leading slash points to "bin/".) Then re-run "ant dist" to rebuild the jar-files to "dist/"-directory. (No need to re-run "ant jnlp" at this point.)

**Fourth bugfix: ddmlib.jar not found / unknown symbol IDevice / ...** - to fix these bugs edit "build.xml" to make use of the "ddmlib.jar" provided with the AndroidScreencast-archive, and not something else (nothing found, or newer version from the Android-SDK, which does not work with the sourcecode). You may have to download "ddmlib.jar" separately from where you downloaded AndroidScreencast. To make "build.xml" use your local "ddmlib.jar"-file now, change line 28...

```
<javac nowarn="true" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpath="${ddmlib}"/>
```

...to:

```
<javac nowarn="true" srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" classpath="ddmlib.jar"/>
```

...and line 35...

```
<copy file="${sdk-ddmlib}" tofile="${dist}/${ddmlib}"/>
```

...to:

```
<copy file="ddmlib.jar" tofile="${dist}/${ddmlib}"/>
```

Phew, that should be it! I now can see my cellphone on my desktop! :-)
(Next step will be rooting the phone (Android 2.3.5) to be able to control it with the mouse & keyboard.)